# How to dismiss keyboard when a user press return button on keyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I'm using [this pod](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) in order to work on text fields and keyboard. In my App.Delegate file, I imported IQKeyboardManagerSwift and enabled it, which works fine now. However, the problem I have now is even when the user tap return key on the keyboard, I cannot dismiss the keyboard and the keyboard remains the same. I added `IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true`, so when the user taps the outside of the keyboard, the keyboard dismisses. I want to add the functionality that when the user tap return button on the keyboard, the keyboard also dismisses. I guess `resignFirstResponder()` will enable this function (Resigns currently first responder field), but I don't know how to implement that function.

I saw some other people use textfieldShouldReturn function, but I think I have to make the function several times if I add code in the view controllers. Currently, I have several text fields, so if possible, I just want to write code only one time.

How can I implement that function?

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.resignFirstResponder()
    
    
    return true
}
....
}
```

Comment: just use textfieldShouldReturn, you only need to write it one time

Comment: @goat_herd 
I thought if I use textfieldShoudReturn, I need to specify which text field I'm going to end editing, like emailTextField.endEditing(true). If I use textfieldShouldReturn, what is gonna be look like in the body of the function and where I should put the function??

Sorry, I'm super beginer and need time for understand everything...

Comment: no, you should use this func:  view.endEditing(true). so you don't need to check what your textField is

Comment: I see. So where I should put the textfieldshouldReturn function? Is it in the AppDelegate?

Comment: no, set delegate of your textField to self in viewDidLoad, and then make your ViewController conform to UITextFiledDelegate and implement textFieldSouldReturn in there, I has post the answer for illustration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set delegate for all your textField to your viewController:

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

then make your viewController comfort to UITextField Delegate:

```
// MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate
extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. So let me confirm in here. If I have several View Controllers, let's say three, and each view controller has two text fields. In that case, I have to add XYZtextfeild.delegate = self two times in each view controllers and write textFieldshouldReturn function for three times in total right?

Comment: no, you need to set textFiled.delegate = self total 6 time , and textFieldSouldReturn 3 times